# Prove: Every connected component in $X \times Y$ is of the form $A \times B$, $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove: Every connected component in $X \times Y$ is of the form $A \times B$, $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$.

I know that a connected component is a maximal closed and open set, but I'm not sure I know how open/closed sets look in the product topology.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, components are closed, but not open. A connected component is a _maximal connected_ set in the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R \subset X \times Y$ be a connected component. Let $A \subset X$ be defined the canonical projection onto $X$ of $R$; that is, $A = \{a \in X : (a,b) \in R \text{ for some } b \in Y\}$. Similarly, let $B$ be the projection onto $Y$ of $R$. If it is true that $A \times B$ is in the product topology (is it?) then you have $R \subseteq A \times B$, ... insert maximality argument here ...